# Reading a XML file using Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I have a xml file that looks like that:

```
<ProductsXML>
    <Product>
       <Name>BLA</Name>
    </Product>
    <Product>
       <Name>KKK</Name>
    </Product>
    <Product>
       <Name>SSS</Name>
   </Product>
    <Product>
       <Name>AAA</Name>
   </Product>   
    <Product>
       <Name>CBA</Name>
    </Product>
    <Product>
       <Name>ABC</Name>
   </Product>
```

I'd like to have a function using JavaScript to check if a Product named: KKK is exists in the file.

Could you please help?

Thanks,

Comment: It is a SO rule that you have to show people what you have done.

Comment: Have you tried using something like this? (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/HTML_to_DOM) did you have any luck? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this. Your xml has to be in `txt` as a string.

```
if (window.DOMParser)
{
    parser=new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(txt,"text/xml");
}
else // Internet Explorer
{
    xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xmlDoc.async=false;
    xmlDoc.loadXML(txt);
}

var products = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Product");
for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {   
    if(products[i].children[0].textContent === "KKK")
        alert("I found KKK")
}
```

Comment: Do you mean I have to write all of my xml file, for example a.xml to a txt file, b.txt and then run the code above on file b?

Comment: No i mean you have to read your file into a string variable called txt.  Or you use the method parseFromFilr

Comment: Ok I think I got it! Thanks!

Comment: Could you just help me with reading my file? I am not using it in a web application. I run it localy. Im trying to build a generator using Yeoman. So my function needs to be in Javascript, and open a XML file, and look for a product inside it. Returning true or false if the product exists in the XML.

Comment: Google it,  you should find enough material on opening files.